# Conduit: Join two sources into one

Tags: haskell, conduit

I have two conduit sources A and B which I want to merge them into one yielding:

```
data Result = Left Int | Value Int | Right Int

merge :: Monad m => Source m Int -> Source m Int -> Source Result
merge a b = undefined
```

such as it:

- Consumes values from both `a` and `b`
- Performs some computation to produce `Value Int`
- As a result of computation either `a` or `b` could have a `leftover`
- When one of the sequences is exhausted the result source should keep producing either `Left` or `Right` values, (depending on which original source still has values) until both sources are exhausted

I tried implementing it with `ZipSource` such as:

```
getZipSource (ZipSource (a =$= CL.map Left) <* ZipSource (b =$= CL.map Right))
```

but I couldn't figure out how to make it alternate between sources (when I do two `await`s) and how to deal with leftovers in a way that I described above.

I also looked at `sequenceSources` but it doesn't seem to help either.

Can something like that be built with Conduit?

A concrete example would be:

- Have two (assumed sorted) `Int` sources
- Get values from both and compare
- Yield the `min` value, subtract it from the biggest and put the remaining back to its stream
- Repeat.

The expected output would be:

```
runConduit $ merge (CL.sourceList [10, 20, 30]) (CL.sourceList [6, 4, 20]) $$ CL.take 10

Value 6    -- 10-6  = 4,  6 yielded, 4 goes back to "a"
Value 4    -- 4-4   = 0,  both values are fully consumed
Value 20   -- 20-20 = 0,  both values are fully consumed
Left 30    -- "b" has no values, but "a" still yielding
```

---

**[UPDATE]**
The best way I found so far is to write something similar to `zipSources` tweaking its internals as:

```
go (Done ()) (HaveOutput src close y) = HaveOutput (go (Done ()) src) close (Nothing, Just y)
go (HaveOutput src close x) (Done ()) = HaveOutput (go src (Done ())) close (Just x, Nothing)
```

Would it be the right way to go?

Comment: Your approach looks fine, though I haven't tested it. You may also want to check out `ZipConduit` to see if it does what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this way:

```
data MergedValue a v b = BackL a v | MergedValue v | BackR v b
data JoinResult a v b = LeftoverL a | JoinValue v | LeftoverR b

joinSources :: Monad m
            => (a -> b -> MergedValue a v b)
            -> Source m a
            -> Source m b
            -> Source m (JoinResult a v b)
joinSources f as bs =
  go (newResumableSource as) (newResumableSource bs)
  where
    go ras rbs = do
      (ras', ma) <- lift $ ras $$++ await
      (rbs', mb) <- lift $ rbs $$++ await
      case (ma, mb) of
        (Nothing, Nothing) -> pure ()
        (Nothing, Just b)  -> yield (LeftoverR b) >> go ras' rbs'
        (Just a,  Nothing) -> yield (LeftoverL a) >> go ras' rbs'
        (Just a,  Just b)  -> case f a b of
          BackL x v -> do
            yield (JoinValue v)
            (nxt, _) <- lift $ ras' $$++ leftover x
            go nxt rbs'
          BackR v x -> do
            yield (JoinValue v)
            (nxt, _) <- lift $ rbs' $$++ leftover x
            go ras' nxt
          MergedValue v -> yield (JoinValue v) >> go ras' rbs'
```